# Determinant of a dual map.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, dual-spaces

I've been trying to solve this problem but i don't know how to proceed. I found a proof online but i really don't understand it.

*Problem:* Prove that $\det(T) = \det(T^*)$, where $T: V \to V$ is a linear map and $T^*$ is the dual of the map $f$, i.e. $T^*: V^* \to V^*$ and $T^*(f) = f \circ T$. Suppose that$ V$ is finite dimensional.

*Proof*: 
Let be $e_1,\cdots,e_n$ base of $V$ and $w_1,\cdots,w_n$ base of $V^*$

(the proof is in the image)

[image: Proof]

Thank you so much.

Comment: I feel like this solution doesn't make much sense... for example, in the first line you have something in $\bigwedge^k V$, which is a dimension 1 vector space, and an $n \times n$ matrix. Should the comma be wedge product? If that's the case and you accept the fact that $\wedge_k V^* = (\wedge_kV)^*$, and using the fact that $T(e_1) \wedge ... \wedge T(e_n) = \det(T) e_1 \wedge ... \wedge e_n$, the answer is kind of immediate. Probably not what the original solution meant to do though.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer. It doesn´t make sense to me neither. Do you have an idea of how i can prove it? It's a little bit urgent @AaronJohnson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for everyone that is looking for the same problem, i found the answer quite simple (without using tensors or wedge product).
You have to proove that

$[T]\quad=\quad{[T*]}^{T}$

since

$det(A)\quad =\quad det({ A }^{ T })$

There's actually another question about how to find a matrix representation of a dual map called

> Matrix Representation of a Dual Map

I hope it was helpfull.

Comment: But the proof of $\det A=\det A^{T}$ is essentially the one in the image.